# How does one control all source of randomness in python reliably with the aid of the user?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scikit-learn

**tl;dr:** I want to be able to seed the functions/code a user provides to me assuming the user wants this functionality and tells me all the random sources of library he/she is using.

The specific scenario I was considering was that I am receiving a function (pointer/handle) and the function is implementing some (nearly) arbitrary program `f` **without threading**. The program is using any pseudorandom functions inside of it **except for the seeding functions** (or functions that might change the random state). There is going to be a master program that runs `f` and needs to be able to essentially change the random seed of `f` at will. So essentially my goal is to run the following pseudocode:

```
seed_all_of_python_reliably(seed=current_seed)
controlled_random_output = f(seed=current_seed) # now f works properly according to my seeding
```

I've had some ideas to make this work properly:

1. have the user that wrote `f` also write `seed_all_of_python_reliably` with some code that makes sure before `f` is ran that its code gets seeded properly too.
2. have the user tell the master code (somehow the part I don't know how to implement in practice) about all the random seeding code it might be using (from numpy, scipy, tensorflow, standard random, scikit etc). Something like in the file where `f` is defined have `tell_about_random_seeding(random.seed, numpy.random.seed, ..., etc)` then the master can just go through the seeding it was told and do the seeding for them.
3. similar to the above but instead have it in a config file where `f` lies (or in reality there might be lots of `f`'s and they might all share the same random code). Then the master can just go through the config file before it goes through all the `f`'s
4. The other solution is I guess to provide an API for using random libraries and a API for seeding things for the user. However, although I don't know how to implement this (i.e. it seems I would have to "inherit" the code from many possible libraries and wrap them with my own which already seems like an ugly solution) but even if I did, it seems every time a user wants to use some library they would have to tell the master at runtime and then the master can inherit it and wrap it or before it runs in the github code the developers can do the wrapping per request. This seems the hardest (due to the massive inheritance) and ugliest (providing a duplicate API for other libraries seem unnecessarily ugly) solution of the four.

Essentially I needed help implementing 2 and 3. Is the way to write this code something as simple as sending function pointers of the seeding function and then just have the master do it? I am hoping there is nothing weird I might be overlooking.

The one thing we **are** assuming is that the user inside of `f` will not call the seeding function in case 2 and 3. I was thinking that its possible to monkey patch them with a `NOP`, however, this can only be done if the user tells us about the seeding functions its using. The assumption is that the user is writing `f` because it wants the help of the master code, so the user isn't Byzantine and won't call seeding functions. So if this assumptions is what I have I can't see why I would need to monkey patch it with NOPs if we trust the user.

Also as an addition to help users, if I decided to do the seeding for them with method 2 or 3 then we could further help the user by seeding the common libraries for them.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this other to inspect all the source code you're interested in to see how/where it's getting 'random' data from. If (by a miracle) you can verify it's all coming from the default PRNG in `random`, then you can seed that. However, it might be complicated by timing issues e.g. if two threads have a race condition to each get random data, then you will still not have deterministic behaviour.

Comment: @TomDalton omg no, there is no threading, `f` is definitively "sequential". Yes I agree its difficult, even if I had an exhaustive list of all sources of randomness and seed them one by one, I would have to keep track of any new sources of randomness in the community. 

However, it feels that all these libraries should have some common source of randomness (the OS? idk what Im not a hardware guy), but if they do , they we could control **that** and then do it.

Comment: "it feels that all these libraries should have some common source of randomness" - nope. Your intuition is wrong here.

Comment: @user2357112 what is the sources of randomness for one fixed machine? Some examples? I'm curious to know how it really works then.

Comment: "**the** source of randomness"? You're *still* assuming a single RNG.

Comment: @user2357112 no Im not. One library could send a query to some server and use its source of randomness. Another could have a black box that has access to quantum states locally and then produces a random number. etc. another maybe to something I have not thought of. I was curious how this worked in practice for some libraries example.

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding random number generation on computers? Most random numbers will actually come from pseudo-random number generators, which are algorithms designed to produce random-looking sequences, while actually being deterministic/repeatable. You can seed PRNGs, but you can't see a 'real' random number generator/library, such as one that uses network traffic, or cosmic radiation as the source of randomness.

Comment: @TomDalton I doubt it, I do know what an RNG are and how they are deterministic. Maybe I went of an tangent when talking about real randomness sources. My apologies.

Comment: I mean that something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getrandom can't be seeded, because is uses 'real' random data provided by the OS rather than a sequence generator.

Comment: The ultimate entropy source for non-cryptographic RNGs is usually the current time at the point when the RNG is initialized. Cryptographic RNGs take entropy from a variety of sources, frequently managed by the OS, such as disk operation speeds and user input keystroke timings, and this usually isn't limited to a single injection of entropy at initialization time. The big problem for you isn't differences like making server requests for random numbers or using quantum randomness; it's the fact that there are even separate RNGs at all, and that more can be created at any time.

Comment: Perhaps if the random number generators are too random, then you don't really want random numbers after all... In most applications where random numbers are used, uncertainty and a large pool of randomness are considered a _good_ thing; you seem to think the opposite...

Comment: Specifically talking about scikit-learn, `numpy.random.seed()` seems plausible for duplicating behaviour in its algorithms.

Comment: @twalberg I think randomness is good too (it provides variation to the outputs). However, I just need to control the starting point i.e. the seeding.